# Как расшифровать пароль MYSQL->user->password

Tags: mysql, криптография

Пароль в базе хранится как **F40A1DD8BD13322642527D1ADC22FA6DF1B1D0ED** Можно ли расшифровать его?

Comment: Нет, потому что скорее всего используются хешевые функции, такие как md5 да хоть бы и crc32 - нет. Если знать алгоритм шифрования, то можно узнать есть ли "словарные" пароли. А так нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это похоже на sha1 хэш (длина 40). 
Расшифровать его - то же самое что и подобрать случайным образом, практически не реально))

Только надеяться на то, что юзер задал простой пароль и получать sha1 хэш всех простых паролей и сравнивать с исходным.

Попробовал пару online-сервисов по дешифровке, но они ничего не знают об этом хэше)

Comment: Ясно.Может ты знаешь как отправить запрос на базу чтобы обновить пароль?.На Havij е Query не работает xD

Comment: @Sauron вот про это стоит уже новый вопрос задать

Comment: @Sauron это ваша база? Подключиться к ней можете?)

Comment: `update users set password=upper(sha1('new_password')) where id=1;`

Comment: Конечно же нет). `update users set password...` я понял но где его отправлять на Havij это не работает в том и дело.

Comment: Сори, про Havij сразу не понял (думал опечатка), никогда не использовал..)

Comment: Чем пользовались можно поделиться)?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ждать 40минут чтобы создать еще одну тему на такой малейший вопрос...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40059/discussion-between-sauron-and-jekaby).

Answer (score 6):

### Нельзя.

Это не шифрование, это хэш встроенной функцией `PASSWORD` в MySQL.

[Говаривают](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46714/password-encryption-type), что в версиях 5.1, 5.5 и 5.6 внутри этой функции к строке с паролем дважды применяется SHA1, но в документации этой детали нет. Вот, можно проверить:

```
SELECT
  SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password'))),
  PASSWORD('password');
```

В документации, впрочем, всё равно сказано, что для любых других целей, кроме как для аутентификации в MySQL этой функцией пользоваться не стоит.