# Хэширование паролей в MySQL

Tags: php, пароль, password-hash

Всем привет!Имеется база данных MySQL.В ней хранится пароль, захешированный через password_hash.Метод PASSWORD_DEFAULT.Можно ли вывести его в админке, чтобы он отображался в незашифрованном виде или нет?

Comment: Нет (и еще 12 символов).

Comment: Связанный вопрос (но не совсем дубликат): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525718/181100

Comment: Обычно предлагается форма для смены пароля, но никак не его отображение так как хеширование одностороннее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, потому что хэширование для того и сделано, чтобы пароль нельзя было расшифровать, получив доступ к админ-панели